# T-SQL: Looking up results based on the result of the table prior to it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if I'm phrasing this question title correctly since I'm still very new to SQL, but this is the best that I can come up with...

So I have two tables a Policy table and a Claims table.
In the policy table, I have the following relevant fields:
[Policy_NO], [Creation_Date], [Limit], [Limit_Date]. Now each policy can have multiple limits, so you might get something that looks like the following table:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| Policy_NO | Creation_Date | Limit | Limit_Date |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  1000 | 8/31/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  2000 | 9/30/2015  |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  5000 | 10/22/2015 |  
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |   500 | 11/17/2015 |  
| A00003    | 9/21/2015     |  3000 | 1/1/2016   |  
+-----------+---------------+-------+------------+
```

The claims table has the following relevant fields of: [Policy_NO], [Claim_NO], and [Claim_Date]

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Policy_NO | Claim_NO | Claim_Date |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| A00001    | CL00001  | 11/16/2015 |
| A00003    | CL00002  | 2/2/2016   |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

So as per the examples above, you should interpret this as, a policy was created in 8/31/2015, and the policy holder requested for limit increases on 9/30/2015 and 10/22/2015. On 11/16/2015, a claim came in, and the limit dropped to 500 from 5000 on 11/17/2015.

I want to create a query (I only have read access btw), that will give me a combined list associated with the correct limit, which a simple right/left join wouldn't be able to do.

So as per the example above, the result in my table regarding Policy A00001 should look like:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------+------------+
| Policy_NO | Creation_Date | Limit |  Limit_Date   | Claim_NO | Claim_Date |
+-----------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------+------------+
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  1000 | 8/31/2015     |          |            |
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  2000 | 9/30/2015     |          |            |
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |  5000 | 10/22/2015    | CL00001  | 11/16/2015 |
| A00001    | 8/31/2015     |   500 | 11/17/2015    |          |            |
+-----------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------+------------+
```

Basically, I want to have a way of easily associating the claim with the right limit date. I've thought about just putting a WHERE to get Claims_Date >= Limit_Date, but that only solves part of my problem. After a claim, the limit would most likely go down, but it could possibly go up in another few months; and my current code would display this claim multiple times with different limits which is incorrect. Bottom line - the claim will only be associated with a policy *once*, so I was hoping that there might be some iterative process that I could use.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your description suggests SQL Server so I removed the mysql tag.  Also, what happens when there are two claims for the same "limit" row?

Comment: Thanks. The situation you described doesn't happen, but if it did, I would like to see two rows with the only difference being the Claim_NO & Claim_Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each claim you can get the policy row using `outer apply`:

```
select c.*, p.*
from claims c outer apply
     (select top 1 p.*
      from policies p
      where p.policy_no = c.policy_no and p.limit_date <= c.claim_date
      order by p.limit_date desc
     ) p;
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the outer apply, so I may be wrong about this.
But, in the code you just gave, wouldn't it still match the Claim to not only the limit on October 22nd and November 17th?

I would only want the claim to be associated with the Oct. 22nd date.

Comment: Ah, I realized now that you had it ordered and had the select top 1.
Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

A "normal" JOIN between the two tables using the Policy_NO as JOIN-Field should do what you requested:

```
SELECT p.Policy_NO, p.Creation_Date, p.Limit, p.Limit_date, c.Claim_NO, Claim_Date
FROM policy AS p, claims AS c
WHERE c.Policy_NO = p.Policy_NO
ORDER BY c.claim_NO, p.Limit_Date ASC
```